# Establishing two-way audio from android to Pi

Tags: raspbian, audio, sip

I want to be able to establish two-way audio from my android based phone to a raspberry pi acting as an intercom over IP. My immediate reaction was to install a SIP client on the Pi that can wait for calls and be configured to automatically answer them.

1. Is this the most effective way to achieve this task, or is there simpler solution?
2. Can the SIP software be set up to wait for a call in this manner, and as it will be sitting behind a NAT device do I need to consider any STUN configuration?

Comment: There are a few possible approaches for SIP outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435648/sip-client-for-raspberry-pi-that-works-from-command-line), but it all looks a bit ropey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a program called mumble. Start a server. Run a client. Bing bang boom done!

Check it out 
Mumble and Mumble Server

Comment: little more detail on the set-up process would be great

Comment: Add PPA using **`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mumble/release`** and setup _**Mumble Server**_ on one of the machines. Now we need to type **`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install -y mumble-server`** now you have a _**Server**_ installed on the _**Host Machine**_ and you can setup some _**Client Machines**_ with _**Mumble Client**_ using the command **`sudo apt install -y mumble`** You can login as admin for the first time using these instructions: **(https://www.mumble.com/support/connecting-to-a-mumble-server-as-admin-for-the-first-time.php)**